# Getting CheckBox id and text when dynamically created using for loop

Tags: android, android-studio, checkbox

I have a Button, questions and multiple checkBoxes created dynamically using for loop that looked like this[image: pic]

This is how i get all the data and how i create the question as well as checkBoxes

```
try {
JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("values");

for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
 JSONObject category = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
 categoryTxt = category.getString("category");
 Log.v("category", categoryTxt);

 //create Question
 TextView title = new TextView(FactorsActivity.this);
 title.setTextSize(20);
 title.setId(i);
 title.setText(categoryTxt);
 title.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
 mLinearLayout.addView(title);

 JSONArray factors = category.getJSONArray("factors");

 Log.v("size factors", String.valueOf(factors.length()));
 nameArray = new String[factors.length()];
 for(int j = 0; j < factors.length(); j++)
 {
  JSONObject factorsObj = factors.getJSONObject(j);
  id = factorsObj.getString("id");
  //Log.v("id", id);
  name = factorsObj.getString("name");
  // Log.v("name", name);

  nameArray[j] = name;

  checkBox = new CheckBox(FactorsActivity.this);
  checkBox.setId(Integer.parseInt(id));
  checkBox.setText(nameArray[j]);
  mLinearLayout.addView(checkBox);

 }
}
```

Now my main objective is, If let say I checked **is daily** box, and I click submit. When i click submit, I want to have all of the selected checkbox information such as the question, its id and its text. The information here should be

1. Question: recurrence of headache
2. checkbox ID: number
3. checkbox Text: is daily
   Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just like you do with `name`, store a reference to the dynamically created `CheckBox` items in an array like this:

```
checkboxArray[j] = checkBox;
```

Then iterate over this array to get the `CheckBox` IDs and their text.

Comment: how to store it when when submit button is clicked?

Comment: As I understand you only want to store the question, checkbox ID and checkbox text. You don't need to store the reference to the checkbox, as that reference will change across app launches.

Comment: I want to store if user clicked the submit button. Because I create dynamically, I dont have idea to resolve it